# Elixir what is the best way to push from anonymous function into an array?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am wondering, what is the best way to obtain results by the given algorithm? The current solution doesn't help because **results** are **nil**. How can I make the variable **results** accessible in **iterate_json** without passing it as an argument?

```
def lookup(json) do
    results = []
    iterate_json(json, fn(x) -> 
        if x["title"] =~ "sunt" do
            results = [x|results]
        end
    end)
    results
end

def iterate_json([head|tail],f) do
    f.(head)
    iterate_json(tail,f)
end

def iterate_json([],f), do: nil
```

Comment: You can do this with Agents if you want but it's not at all idiomatic. What are you trying to achieve here? Maybe there's a better solution for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: it is not really a problem, i would just like to learn elixir and not sure how to solve things like this (for example a recursion that will push something into an array only on a given condition but i need to somehow keep the state of the array so its not empty - you can of course pass it as an argument but i really don't like that one)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`Enum.map`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#map/2) ?

Comment: Or maybe [`List.foldl/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#foldl/3) or [`List.foldr/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#foldr/3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few different issues with this code. The main is one cannot access the parent context from within a closure (even in Ruby that won’t change the `results` variable:

```
results = nil
fn(x) -> results = 42 end.()
results
#⇒ nil
```

> *warning:* variable "`results`" is unused
>
> Note variables defined inside `case`, `cond`, `fn`, `if` and similar do not leak. If you want to conditionally override an existing variable "`results`", you will have to explicitly return the variable. For example:

The above is what `iex` spits out when one tries to execute this code.

---

> How can I make the variable `results` accessible in `iterate_json` without passing it as an argument?

It’s accessible in `iterate_json`. The value that was set upfront is captured and used within a closure. What you cannot do, is you cannot change it from inside a closure.

What you are trying to achieve, is actually a [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) operation:

```
def lookup(json) do
  Enum.reduce(json, [], fn x, acc ->
    if x["title"] =~ "sunt", do: [x|acc], else: acc
  end)
end
```

Comment: Your first statement is not quite correct. You can certainly _access_ the parent context, but you can not change it, hence variable redefinitions will not work.

Comment: @dualed it’s a terminology culprit: this is the _closure context_ you might access, that is strictly speaking not exactly the same as _parent context_.

Comment: Since you can read any upvalue from any encompassing lexical scope (as far as I'm aware) I don't see your distinction, could you elaborate?